# Как сделать перемещение камеры как в hollow knight?

Tags: c#, unity3d, камера

только начал пару месяцев назад осваивать юнити и очень приглянулось перемещение камеры как в Hollow Knight, что камера перемещаться в соответствии от направления движения игрока(вправо или влево)

Answer (score 1):

По-факту там реализовано 2 логики.

1. Камера держит персонажа по центру экрана и следует за ним.
2. Камера отодвигается когда доходит до краев уровня.

1 - реализовать просто -- камера повешена на персонажа(перетянуть внутрь персонажа в инспекторе обьектов сцены). В таком случае персонаж будет всегда в центре камеры.

2 - реализовать уже сложнее. Нужно обозначить границы движения камеры и "поправлять" ее положение если она в эти границы упирается.

В общем и целом с 2 пока что можешь и не заморачитваться, на самом деле. 1 - главное.

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать!

Answer (score 1):

Вокруг цели создается прямоугольник если цель выходит за его пределы, то камера следует за ним.

```
[SerializeField] private Transform lookAt;
[SerializeField] private Vector2 bound = new Vector2(0.15f, 0.05f);

private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 delta = Vector3.zero;

        float deltaX = lookAt.position.x - transform.position.x;
        if(deltaX > bound.x || deltaX < -bound.x)
        {
            if (transform.position.x < lookAt.position.x)
            {
                delta.x = deltaX - bound.x;
            }
            else
            {
                delta.x = deltaX + bound.x;
            }
        }
   
        float deltaY = lookAt.position.y - transform.position.y;
        if (deltaY > bound.y || deltaY < -bound.y)
        {
            if (transform.position.y < lookAt.position.y)
            {
                delta.y = deltaY - bound.y;
            }
            else
            {
                delta.y = deltaY + bound.y;
            }
        }

        transform.position += new Vector3(delta.x, deltaY, 0);
    }
```

Comment: "выходит за его пределы"? Или наоборот?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше для настройки камеры подключить Cinemachine через Package Manager. Это клевый инструмент для настройки камер, и там большинство работы уже сделано за нас остаётся только нужные компоненты подключить, и настроить по вкусу. После установки менюшка появляется сверху[image: Вот она].

Там нам нужна 2D камера, её объект автоматически добавиться в сцену, на нем компонент для настройки [image: Тут все достаточно понятно].

Остается только поставить цель для наблюдения, туда естественно героя надо закинуть[image: Все очень просто].

Далее самое интересное, в Play Mode мы можем можем настраивать зоны взаимодействия игрока с камерой[image: Должен быть выбран объект той 2D камеры!].

Далее все достаточно просто, желтая точка возвращается в перекрестие синих линий при остановке движения. И если раздвинуть эти синие линии то в них создаётся пространство, в котором камера не начинает движение[image: При их пересечении начинается движение камеры].

Красные же линии это грубо говоря граница, при ее пересечении начнётся резкое перемещение камеры. Думаю надо просто поиграться с этими полосками и получиться то что надо, и велосипеды писать не придется.

Вот документация по ней Cinemachine если понадобиться https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.8/manual/index.html.

Comment: Спасибо за очень подробное пояснение буду пробовать